# Exit a program when IF statement == true?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a program computes and prints how many real solutions for the given equation.
the User enter the values for A,B and C.
And I want the program to exit if the user entered a value for A = 0 and not to continue asking for the others value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for A : ");
    int coA = s.nextInt();

    if (coA==0){
        System.out.println("Error ! Enter a vlaue larger than 0 ");
    };
    System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for B : ");
    int coB = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for C : ");
    int coC = s.nextInt();

    double coTotal = (Math.pow(coB, 2))-4*coA*coC;

    if(coTotal>0){
        System.out.println(" The System has two solutions ");
    }
    if (coTotal==0){
        System.out.println(" The System has one solutions ");
    }
    if(coTotal<0){
        System.out.println(" The System has ZERO solutions ");
    } 
}
```

Comment: `return`? You have to show _where_ this code is. Is it in a function? There are various ways of controlling the control flow.

Comment: `if (coA == 0) { System.exit(); }`, basically? Which begs the question of why you tell the user that 0 is no acceptable, if you want to use 0 to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is in `main` you can use System.exit, like this. I used -1 to indicate there was an issue with the input. You could use a different error code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for A : ");
int coA = s.nextInt();

if (coA==0){
    System.out.println("Error ! Enter a vlaue larger than 0 ");
    System.exit(-1);
};
System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for B : ");
int coB = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter a vlaue for C : ");
int coC = s.nextInt();

double coTotal = (Math.pow(coB, 2))-4*coA*coC;

if(coTotal>0){
    System.out.println(" The System has two solutions ");
}
if (coTotal==0){
    System.out.println(" The System has one solutions ");
}
if(coTotal<0){
    System.out.println(" The System has ZERO solutions ");
}
```